# How to encrypt and unencrypt an email address to anonymize data

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography

I have data that contains a unique email address.  I need to encrypt the email address for the purpose of anonymizing the data before sharing it with someone else.  They will perform a task on the anonymized data and share it back with me, and I will then want to unencrypt the unique identifier to reveal the email address related the the new data. I've seen examples using the `base64` library, but I'm concerned that someone else could easily unencrypt what I send them.

How can I use Python to create a reliable method to anonymize email address within my dataset, but still be able to deanonymize when needed?

Comment: Generate a random address. Save the mapping between the random addresses and the real addresses in a database or file.

Comment: You probably don't need cryptography for this.

Comment: Base64 isn't cryptography, it's an encoding format. There is no secret key and anyone can convert a string to/from base64. What Barmar told you should suffice for your needs.

Comment: If you *really* need cryptography then encrypt the email address, convert it to Base64 and insert into your text.  reverse the process to decrypt.  Since an email address is short I would suggest AES-CTR so as not to have to add padding.  However, as @Barmar said, encryption is probably overkill for what you seem to need.